# Restrict a user to access only a specific folder in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

I have created a new user in my Ubuntu server and I want to give him access only in one specific folder and its contains. Nothing else. How can I do that in the terminal?

Comment: Use chown to make the new user the owner of the folder you want him to have access to. Set the permissions to 755 for this new folder. To restrict the new user from viewing anything else, you'd have to set the permissions of all other folders to something like 700. Read the documentation for chmod and chown for more details

Comment: @ Prateek Dewan What if I don't want to change the ownership of the folder?

Comment: @user1919 **chown** is not used to restrict, It is used to allow rather. Are you trying to give him FTP access or SSH? That means if you want user to SSH but to a specific directory only.